# ASP.NET Web App freezing on an exception, dw20.exe hanging at 100% CPU

Tags: asp.net, drwatson

Apologies for the open endedness of this question, but I really don't know what to say.

I've done *something* to my ASP.NET MVC Web Application to cause an exception which is probably occuring due to an NHibernate mapping error to cause dw20.exe to run at ~ 50% CPU usage (100% on one core). The browser doesn't respond until IIS times out, and the debugger never hits an exception, everything just freezes :s

Anyone got any ideas as to where to start with this?

I'm on windows server 2008, vs2008, .net 3.5

Edit: found a few of these in eventlog

Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 7.0.6001.18000, time stamp 0x47919413, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 6.0.6001.18215, time stamp 0x49953395, exception code 0xe053534f, fault offset 0x000442eb, process id 0x%9, application start time 0x%10.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: dw20 running at 50% usage says to me that it's spinning at 100% on one of your cores (you probably have a dual core cpu)

Comment: Can you repro, or does it happen at random?

Comment: wow what an idiot, i didnt even realise this was a dual core machine! ha! yes, 100% on one core. I'll check for a SO. Its happening to me all the time since i made some changes at work, then come to do more on my home pc and its freezing on me :s

Comment: ok restarted and now VS is dropping out with a stackoverflow exception as i'd normally have expected! must have got VS into a mess. Thanks for the tips anyway, mausch post a proper answer for votage :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enough information here to be sure, but I'd try tossing FxCop at the code and see if it picks up anything.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a dump and analyze it with DebugDiag.
More details [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151125115506/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/tess/archive/2009/03/20/debugging-a-net-crash-with-rules-in-debug-diag.aspx).